# Can't access my site please help

Tags: errors

Today morning I saw that 3 plugins were asking for update then I updated 1 of them and my site got crashed now I can't access my site not even my wp admin panel please look into the site see if you can help me here is my site http://rtadvise.com

Answer (score 1):

It's Loading fine for me both the site and the wp-admin login page.

If you are struggling with recently updated plugins,  Login to FTP and manually remove the plugins so you can gain access again.   You can then reinstall them one by one to narrow down the problem.

It might also be worth clearing your cookies and cache incase its a localised problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advise I deleted that plugin and then my website have started working BTW thanks again for your kind support

Answer (score 1):

This happens from time to time with Wordpress plugins and often, you are not sure which plugin is the problem because you may have updated a number of plugins or a different plugin may conflict an updated plugin. My approach for resolving this sort of issue is as follows:

1. Log in through FTP
2. Go to the directory wp-content
3. Create a subdirectory called 'temp'
4. Move all the subdirectories from the plugins folder to 'temp'
5. Go back to your site and open it - it should work now unless the plugins were not the problem
6. Move the sub-directories in 'temp' back to 'plugins' one at a time and check the site (refresh each time ctrl+ F5)
7. When the site stops working, the last plugin moved back will be the problem.
8. Delete the plugin and move the remaining plugins back to the 'plugin' directory from 'temp'
9. Check the site - if it still works then you have identified and removed the issue.
10. Delete the empty 'temp' directory

This iterative approach has always worked for me. There may be better approaches and I will watch this post with interest in case someone else offers something better. I hope this helps you resolve your problem.

Comment: If you already know or suspect which plugin caused the problem, just move that one into temp in step 6 and if the site works again then you have resolved the problem.